# Confusion about separability of the space $\ell^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, separable-spaces

I found the following result:       **$\ell^2$ is not separable.**

The proof use this claim as corollary.

> Let $(E, d)$ a metric space.  If there exist  $B\subseteq E$ uncountable such that for all $b_1$, $b_2\in B$ separate we have $d(b_1, b_2)\geq 1$ then  $E$ is not séparable.

**Proof:**
Note each element of $\ell^2$ is written as
  $$(x_n)_n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n e_n.$$

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$, we put

\begin{align*}
 T_A: \ell^2  & \to \ell^2: \\
 \sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n e_n & \mapsto \sum_{n\in A} x_n e_n.
 \end{align*}

It is easy to check that $T_A$ is well defined, linear and continuous.
  (we have $\|T_A\|= $1 if $A$ is not empty, otherwise $T_A$ is the null map).
  The set $B = \{T_A\mid A\subseteq \mathbb{N} \}$ check the assumptions of the
  which is a corollary to the fact that it is an uncountable set 
  of $\mathscr  L(\ell^2)$, and given $A, A^{\prime}\subseteq \mathbb{N}$, $A\neq A^{\prime}$,
  then it exists (without loss of generality, even if it means exchanging $A$ and $A^{\prime}$)
  $n\in A\setminus A^{\prime}$, hence $T_A(e_n) = $1 and $T_{A^{\prime}}(e_n) = 0$, thus
  $\|T_A - T_{A^{\prime}}\|\geq 1$.

> I'm confused about that as far as I know $\ell^2$ is separable as a Hilbert space.

Please help me to clarify this misunderstanding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it showing that $\mathscr L(\ell^2) $ is not separable?

Comment: Like Berci said, this is a proof that the space of bounded linear operators $\ell^2 \rightarrow \ell^2$ is not separable, not that $\ell^2$ itself is not separable. The set of finite $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combinations of $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ forms a countable dense subset of $\ell^2$ itself.

Comment: Looking at $\{\chi_A\mid A\subseteq \mathbb{N}\}$ one can show with the claim that $\ell^{\infty}$ is not separable, though.